# Data redundancy - JOIN with large result set

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization, redundancy

I have an issue with data redundancy. My JOIN query in MySQL creates a very large data set (~8mb) while a lot of the data is redundant. After analysis, I can see that the query is fast, but the data transfer can take several seconds. What options do I have?

For example, say that I have the two tables

Users:

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |
| 2 | Joe |

And Purchases:

| user_id | purchase_id | purchase_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 |
| 2 | B | 200 |
| 1 | C | 300 |
| 1 | D | 400 |

If I simply LEFT Join the tables with

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, purchase_id, purchase_amount 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON users.id = purchases.user_id
```

I will end up with a result:

| user_id | user_name | purchase_id | purchase_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | A | 100 |
| 2 | Joe | B | 200 |
| 1 | Alex | C | 300 |
| 1 | Alex | D | 400 |

However, as we can see, the user_id 1 and user_name Alex exists in three places. For very large result sets this can become an issue.

I'm thinking about using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT to reduce the redundancy. Is this in general a good idea? My first tests seem to work, but I have to set the MySQL `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` which might not be a good thing since I don't know what to set it to.

For example I could do something like

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(purchase_id, ':', purchase_amount)) 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON users.id = purchases.user_id 
GROUP BY user_id, user_name
```

And end up with a result:

| user_id | user_name | GROUP_CONCAT... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | A:100,C:300,D:400 |
| 2 | Joe | B:200 |

Are there any other options for me? Is this the way to go? Parsing the concatenated column is not an issue. I am trying to solve the large data set being returned.

Comment: You can select specific columns instead of `users.*`, to reduce the amount of redundant information that has to be transferred.

Comment: I need all columns of users as I do in the concat/group by example.

Comment: Another option is to do separate queries in the application program. Do one query to get all the `users` information, loop through that and do a separate query to get their purchases. This is usually considered poor design, but if the methods you described don't work well it may be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @Barmar I have considered that. But it is not an option as that would result in thousands of queries. Do you see any issues with the GROUP_BY approach?

Comment: Then I think you're stuck with the two options you show in the question. For the `GROUP_CONCAT()` you could do a first query to get the maximum length of the concatenation, then set `group_concat_max_len` larger than that. But that might be expensive. You could estimate from the maximum value of `COUNT(*) GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: `For very large result sets this can become an issue.` Just to observe, this hasn't been my experience, but perhaps your 'very large' is orders of magnitude larger than mine.

Comment: mariadb changed the default group_concat_max_len to 1M a number of years ago; I hope mysql follows suit at some point.  also consider using json_arrayagg or json_objectagg, which don't have a limit

Comment: Do you need all the data?  Why?  Usually, one writes a SQL to filter, summarize, or condense the data -- rather than shoveling all of it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. we can have temp table in between?
2. use apache spark's map reduce to get data in desired format.